# Parse Date android 0-24 with 12:00

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a String in my mySqldb: 2016-09-14 12:00:00, and in my app I would like get only hour so 12:00 but use 0-24h. 
Example:

```
input > 2016-09-14 12:00:00 output > 12:00:00
input > 2016-09-14 14:00:00 output > 14:00:00
input > 2016-09-14 08:00:00 output > 08:00:00
```

So I tried with

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

but return

```
output > 12:00
output > 02:00
output > 08:00
```

So with without 14:00
I tried with

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
```

but return

```
output > 24:00
output > 14:00
output > 08:00
```

so with 24:00 instead 12:00

And also with:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

but return

```
output > 00:00
output > 14:00
output > 08:00
```

so with 00:00 instead 12:00

How can have output

```
12:00
14:00
08:00
```

Comment: I don't really got what your goal is

Comment: I want setText hour in TextView parsing date from db but hour 0-24 so if in my db I have 14/09/2016 12:00:00 Set text 12:00 but if I have 14/09/2016 14:00:00 set text 14:00 and if I have 14/09/2016 08:00:00 set Text with 08:00

Comment: About your title containing the text "0-24" please note that the special time 24:00 (midnight at end of day) cannot be printed or parsed with `SimpleDateFormat`-API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

To

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Your input is in 24 hour format, not 12 hour format.

Output should be:

```
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thank you! you're right, at HH instead of hh in the input I would not have noticed even in 100 years :D !!